# Datetime string in HQL

Tags: hql, castle-activerecord

I am using Castle ActiveRecord for my application. My problem is how to use a datetime string in HQL like this (without using parameters):

```
"from Contact c where c.DayOfBirth = '5/3/1988'"
```

Comment: What is problem? Does it error, or just return the wrong result?

Answer (score 1):

Try using YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
from Contact c where c.DayOfBirth = '1988-05-03'
```

Comment: Thank you, Scheffer. I have tried: "from Contact c where c.DayOfBirth = 1988-05-03" and the query can execute without throw an exception, but it did not return any record.

Comment: @Trần Quốc Bình: you probably want `where c.DayOfBirth between '1988-05-03' and '1988-05-04'`

Comment: @Trần Quốc Bình: are you sure you have any records in the table with such DayOfBirth?

Comment: @Trần Quốc Bình: Use a profiler (http://nhprof.com) or set the key `show_sql` in your app.config to true. Once you get a hold of the query Castle is executing you can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but I can not find out the real query.